# Can't find the source of .NET error, need Help

Tags: c#, .net, 2d, sfml

I am using .NET Framework 2.0 to program a 2d platformer. I am using SFML .NET as it is Cross-Platform and supported by MONO and has a mature API. My problem is that although my program compiles properly and runs properly, I get an error while closing it.

> The instruction at "0x5ed0530e" referenced memory at "0x0000051c". The memory could not be "read"

After careful debugging I have noticed that the problem occurs after I initialize the SFML String2d Class.

What is wrong; why does this error occur when closing the program? And even if nothing is wrong is there anyway to stop receiving the error so that the users of my program don't get annoyed by it?

using System;
using SFML.Graphics;
using SFML.Window;

```
namespace ProGUI
{
    class TextBox : Sprite
    {
        private String2D Text;
        public TextBox(RenderWindow App)
        {
            Image = new Image(App.Width, App.Height / 4, new Color(0, 0, 0));
            Position = new Vector2(0, App.Height - App.Height / 4);
        }

        public void SetText(string text)
        {
            Text = new String2D(text);
            Text.Font = new Font("Greyscale_Basic_Bold.ttf");
            Text.Position = new Vector2(Position.X + 5, Position.Y + 5);
            Text.Size = 12;
        }

        public string GetText()
        {
            return Text.Text;
        }

        public void Render(RenderWindow App)
        {
            App.Draw(this);
            App.Draw(Text);
        }

        public void MainLoop(RenderWindow App, Color clr)
        {
            while (App.IsOpened())
            {
                App.Clear(clr);

                App.DispatchEvents();

                App.Draw(this);
                App.Draw(Text);

                App.Display();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there is no dodgy code. Absolutely clean and simple.

Comment: That error sounds like its coming from unmanaged code or a COM component.  Was a stack trace included with the error?  Can you post the code where the error is occuring?

Comment: Try enabling native code debugging.

Comment: @SLaks How do you do that in Visual C#?

Comment: @burningprodigy: Is that code being called while your app is shutting down? If so, why?

Comment: @Jon No, it isn't. In fact its being called almost at the start but the error shows up after my program gets closed. It is caused by this code as it doesn't come when I don't use the String2d class.

Comment: @burningprodigy: Well, that doesn't mean it's *really* related to that code. Maybe it is, maybe it isn't... but errors like this can have deep and surprising causes.

Comment: 1) Comment you 4 lines of code
2) try it.
3) It works ? then uncomment the first line and go to step 2)
 ==> that way you'll know what line cause the problem (if the problem is associated with on of those 4 lines)

Comment: Very much disagree nothing is wrong. You've at least failed to validate arguments, account for integer overflows and properly dispose of resources.

Comment: In the Debug tab in Project Properties

Comment: Probably not the source of your error, but do you ever call `Dispose` on the `Font` objects that you create? Since you always use the same font, there is no need to re-create the object each time; create it once and store it in a field, that will remove some unnecessary processing and memory pressure.

Comment: "even INDENTS although C# is a static-typed language" does not make much sense. And that casts some doubts on "I checked everything".

Comment: @Everybody. Ok So maybe I am not the best of programmers. So i am posting the whole class as I am pretty sure the problem is in that class.

Comment: @Jared is checking for integer overflow necessary, can't i just use the **checked+** cmd option?

Comment: @burningprodigy: if you do that, on overflow it throws an OverflowException. Is that what you want?

Comment: Umm no. I better use try/catch loops and the **checked** _operator_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does the SFML String2d class implement IDisposable? Do you dispose all instances correctly?

It might be that the finalizer thread is disposing them when they are in an invalid state.

Answer (score 3):

You would be better off asking this question on the SFML forums. A quick Google turned up [this thread](http://www.sfml-dev.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4412) which suggests that there is a problem with the String2D type.

Answer (score 3):

This code will recursive infinitely:

```
    public void Render(RenderWindow App)
    {
        App.Draw(this);
        App.Draw(Text);
    }
```

since `App.Draw`, called on a `Sprite` `x`, will call `x.Render(App)`. So `App.Draw(this)` will internally call `this.Render(App)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try "EditBin.exe /NXCOMPAT:NO C:\AppName.exe" from a visual studio command line after your app is compiled.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll find is that the `String2d` class either:

- Has a bug

or (more likely, given the description of your problem)

- Is being called at the wrong point in the app's lifecycle.

For example, is the container for the `Text` property initialised at this point? Are multiple threads accessing the `Text` property at the same time (I'm thinking of some sort of game-loop, in your case)?

To me, since this happens when your app is closing, I expect this `SetText` method is being called during shutdown, *after* the form/window has been disposed by the runtime. If you put code to set `this.Text` in the form's `Closed` event, you'd get similar results.